# Joining a pointer and member pointer into a function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, member-pointers

Please consider such code:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    void MyFunc(int x){
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    MyClass* class_ptr = new MyClass();
    void (Myclass::*member_func_ptr)(int) = &MyClass::MyFunc;

    // This should output '5'.
    (class_ptr->*member_func_ptr)(5);

    /* ??? */

    // I want the following to output '5' exactly the same way as previous call.
    func_ptr(5);
}
```

How should I complete this code to have `func_ptr(...)` call the MyFunc from `*class_ptr`?

If it is possible, I would love to somehow **join a `MyClass*` and a `void (Myclass::*)(int)` into a `void (*)(int)`**.

If not, I expect a clever usage of `std::mem_fn` and `std::function` (or other functional utilities) might do the trick.

Ideally, I'd like a C++11 solution (since e.g. `std::mem_fun` is now deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a plain function pointer, but you can get a function object using `bind` or a lambda:

```
auto bound = std::bind(member_func_ptr, class_ptr, std::placeholders::_1);
auto lambda = [=](int x){return (class_ptr->*member_func_ptr)(x);}

bound(5);  // should output 5
lambda(5); // should output 5 too
```

Both of these can be converted to `std::function<void(int)>` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a function pointer from a member pointer and an object pointer. What you can get is a function object with the same call notation using, e.g., `std::bind()`:

```
std::bind(member_func_ptr, class_ptr, _1)
```

You can the use this function object to initialize, e.g., a `std::function<void(int)>`.